# I want to send circular reference JSON from client side to server side

Tags: json, reactjs, circular-dependency

I am sending body: `Flatted.stringify(object)` with header: `'Content-type': 'application/json'` from client side to server side in React. On client side when I print `console.log(Flatted.stringify(object))` then it will appear like `[{'a': '1'}]` which can be easily parsed from `Flatted.parse()` method. But the issue is on the server-side when I send `Flatted.stringify(object)` in the body it will become like this `[{a: '1'}]` and cannot be parsed using `Flatted.parse()` function.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of replacing the outer curly braces in the string with squared braces you can just do something like this:

```
var jsonString = Flatted.stringify(object)
var stringWithSquaredBraces = "[" + stringToReplace.substring(1,stringToReplace.length-1) + "]"

var parsedObject = Flatted.parse(stringWithSquaredBraces)
```

Comment: I forgot to add square bracket although this is resolved for me, thanks for responding!

Comment: I have done like JSON.stringify(Flatted.stringify(object_name: object))